# Functioning of Random, C#

Tags: c#, random

I have a question about working of Random in C#. Say I want to call some function if variable i == 0. I have the following code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = rnd.Next(5);
if (i == 0){
   myFunction();
}
```

So, I would call myFunction() one time per 5 launches of the program. And what if I had another code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    int i = rnd.Next(50);
    if (i == 0){
       myFunction();
    }
}
```

Would I have the same result in the final? (calling of myFunction() one time per 5 launches of the program)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really a programming question, it's a math question.

Comment: Yes, `myFunction()` would _on average_ be called also once every 5 launches.

Comment: If you wanted the code to run *exactly* once every five program launches, you'd have to do something like storing the count to the Registry.

Comment: @ZoharPeled random could function differently in different programming languages, so it's not only about the math

Comment: So what is the question then, if it's not about the statistics?

Comment: @ZoharPeled it's about statistics and implementation of Random in C#

Comment: Once you have the statistics figured out, what is your question about the .Net random implementation?

Comment: @ZoharPeled the practical experience of using of random which could be a little different than in the statistics

Comment: Main difference would be that in the 2nd solution you could have 2 or more calls in one launch.

Comment: `Random.Next(n)` should ideally work exactly like rolling an n-sided die and subtracting 1 from the result. It doesn't work *exactly* like that because it's a pseudo-random number generator, but it's close enough for many purposes, and specificially it's close enough for the code in your post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give it a try, running this **several** times :

```
class Program
{
    static int _caseOneCount = 0;
    static int _caseTwoCount = 0;

    static Random _rnd = new Random();

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var max = 100000;

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < max ; i++ )
        {
            CaseOne();
            CaseTwo();

            Console.WriteLine( _caseOneCount.ToString() + "/" + _caseTwoCount.ToString() );
        }
    }

    static void CaseOne()
    {
        if ( _rnd.Next( 5 ) == 0 )
            _caseOneCount++;
    }

    static void CaseTwo()
    {
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
            if ( _rnd.Next( 50 ) == 0 )
                _caseTwoCount++;
    }
}
```

You will see that the results are nearly equivalent and close to 20% as expected.

Edit : Now if you run CaseOne and CaseTwo **only once**, you can have :

- CaseOne : only 0 or 1,
- CaseTwo : a value from 0 to 10

Edit 2 : following the comments of @Jean-ClaudeColette. The second case corresponds to a binomial distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

So as results, the probability to have :

- 0 call is 81.7%
- 1 call is 16.7%
- 2 calls is 1.5%
- more is 100% minus the above which is around 0.086%

But the average value stays 20%.

Which means indeed that applying the second case only once will lead to a different result compared to the first case.

Random and its details are in the documentation :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

And the description of the inner algorithm (Knuth subtractive random generator) is described here (with a C# implementation which is not the .Net implementation but a way to see how it works) :
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Subtractive_generator

Comment: Your code sample is not really a fair comparison between P(rand(5)==0) and P(rand(50)==0). Instead it's comparing P(rand(5)==0) and P(rand(50)==0)*10, and that's why they are both 20%.

Comment: @Helen The distributions are binomial, but the parameters are different. You are looking for the probability of getting k calls of MyFunction in n trials. The probability of calling MyFunction being equal to p, the probability of getting k calls of MyFunction is C_n^k * p^k * (1-p)^{n-k}. We have to compare the results for k fixed, obtained for p = 1/5 and p = 1/50 and different numbers of trials n and 10*n

Comment: @BobbyAndJoe, I interpreted the question as comparing P(rand(5)==0) and P(rand(50)==0)*10

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette You know, in my program I have the same result for both cases: say if I run the program for 100 times, I have nearly the same number of myFunction() calls. Now I understand why

Answer (score 0):

Actually both your above statements were wrong.

For your first loop, there is no guarantee that your function will get called one time per 5 launches - but if you run it enough times the probability of your function got called is 1/5.

For your second code sample, the probability is 1/50 instead. And your outer (j) loop just controls how many "launches" you are going to run using your words - it doesn't change the probability.

Comment: I know there is no guarantee, I was talking about the probability. So does one 1/5 probability equal to ten 1/50 probabilities? :)

Comment: You invest $10 and get $1 back, your profit rate is 10%. Now you invest five $10, does you profit rate become 50%?